# How to run Total Commander 64bit under the Digital Guardian Platform or TortoiseSVN 32bit on a 64bit OS

Tags: tortoisesvn, 32bit-64bit, total-commander

My company recently deployed the *Digital Guardian Platform* (https://digitalguardian.com/products/digital-guardian-platform). Now Total Commander 64bit shows the following error upon startup:

> This application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK
>   to close application.

The only help I found was the tip to install the 32bit version. That worked. However now I am missing the icon overlays from TortoiseSVN 64bit. This annoyance can be solved by installing the 32bit version of TortoiseSVN as well. BUT as of version 1.7.something the TortoiseSVN installer doesn't let you install the 32bit version on a 64bit OS.
Does anyone know whether it is either possible to run Total Commander 64bit under the Digital Guardian Platform or TortoiseSVN 32bit on a 64bit OS?